# составить программу, если точка принадлежит закрашеной области - вывести true

Tags: c#, .net, геометрия

[image: график]

Если точка x;y принадлежит закрашеной области - вернуть true
Пересечение области считается thue тоже. 
 - вывести true
C#

Comment: принадлежит чему?

Comment: закрашеной области

Comment: @Grundy Если точка принадлежит некту.

Comment: @АртурБелов Это кому такое задание?

Comment: да задачка такая вот

Comment: Ваше задание понятно, но вопрос то в чем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эх, вы ж вроде не первый год на площадке, пора бы знать, как задавать вопросы:)

Код, думаю, писать не стоит, вы и сами справитесь, а вот с понятием ограничений областей, видимо, проблема, поэтому вот вам картинка, где показано, как формируется эта область:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На рисунке приведены две окружности. ([манхэттенская метрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Первая |x|+|y|=4, вторая |x|+|y|=2. Нам нужно проверить, что точка попала в кольцо.

```
if ((Math.Abs(x)+Math.Abs(y)<=4) && (Math.Abs(x)+Math.Abs(y)>=2)){
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
        }
```